# SQL loop or alternative

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to gather a timestamp by day of turnover, it has to be run live so I cant store the data.

So the basic principal is that I need to see when a job was created, and then see if the delivery date is in a certain period. This then gives me a result. I then need to loop that for the total number of days in the month.

The code below works in a fashion in that It gathers the data, but it doesn't spit it out in 1 extract.

I need a procedure that will gather a time stamp function on various data

```
DECLARE @a int; 
Set @a = 1
While @a <=31
Begin

Select

'2016-10-' + convert(varchar(3),@a),
Sum(mjob.Value) as value

From jobdetails as mjob

Where mjob.createDate <= '2016-10-' + convert(varchar(3),@a)

 --this has to increment based on the @a
AND mjob.DeliveryTime between '2016-10-01' and '2016-11-01'--this stays the same throughout the given month

Set @a = @a +1

END
```

Comment: So every month you have to modify your procedure? Changing the between dates and the @a variable (remembering whether it's a leap year or not and how many days are in the current month)? Sounds like a lot of hassle... Also, you are comparing dates with strings, which is not a good setup. You'd better rethink the whole thing, and think of the data as a set, not RBAR.

Answer (score 0):

SUM() can also be used as a window function, with a `<window frame preceding>` to get cumulative sums.

At least on [MS Sql Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms189461(v=sql.110).aspx) and beyond.

```
select createDate, 
sum(Value) over (partition by year(createDate), month(createDate) order by createDate rows unbounded preceding) AS CumulativeValue
from JobDetails
where CreateDate between '2016-10-01' and '2016-10-31'
and DeliveryTime between '2016-10-01' and '2016-11-01';
```